# How to load an external https site in iOS Safari without showing the URL and without Phonegap?

Tags: html, ios, iframe, https, safari

I am running into an issue for which I can't seem to find a working solution (and which may perhaps be impossible to solve the way I want to do it).

Here's what I want to do: 
We have an application on a server (let's call it XYZ for this example) that supports client branded views with a login screen. In order to access the proper branded view, we need to call the site as follows (in any browser): https://XYZ/client/clientname 
So far, so good. The above works as expected.

Now, in order to not need specific DNS entries from clients, using a subdomain of their main domain, we want to be able to provide them with a small HTML 'wrapper' around the above style URL in such a way that they can place it on their servers. The idea is then that their visitors can go to e.g. the following URL: http://some.client.url in such a way that that last mentioned URL stays visible in the browser's location bar, but that the first mentioned external HTTPS URL is actually loaded in the page.

O.k., easy enough to achieve that with an iframe or normal frameset, right? 
Well, yes, on normal browsers doing just that is allowed. But... when trying to call the client's wrapper URL in Safari on iOS, I just see a white page. 
Googling this type of issue points me in two directions (both of which I already feared):
-iOS Safari may not allow external sites to be loaded like this in an (i)frame.
-iOS Safari may have trouble loading an SSL site in an (i)frame this way.

It can also be a combination of the two above things.

When searching for solutions for this I cannot seem to find a good solution. My search results are extremely 'polluted' by most of the hits being about similar issues using Phonegap (which is not what we want to use).

So, the question basically becomes simple enough: Is it possible to achieve what I want using some kind of normal HTML wrapper (if necessary using jQuery in it is o.k. too, but preferably not)? 
If so: can anyone tell me how to do it?
If not: are there alternatives to achieving this, without having to resort to things like Phonegap or to letting a subdomain of the client point to our servers and take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

One more possible way, Try with UIWebView